# Enale and disable SEARCH_LONG_PRESS in Android applications

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want my application to be opened by long-pressing search button, but I want to add the option to deactivate this.

I added to my shortcutActivity this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

so when I long-press the search button it is opened, but now, I have to be able to turn this feature on.

This is not the main activity, this activity just calls to the main one and then finish().

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find a particular response useful, please upvote it. If a response is the correct answer to your question. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunently intent filters are static

> An intent filter is an instance of the IntentFilter class. However, since the Android system must know about the capabilities of a component before it can launch that component, intent filters are generally not set up in Java code, but in the application's manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) as  elements. (The one exception would be filters for broadcast receivers that are registered dynamically by calling Context.registerReceiver(); they are directly created as IntentFilter objects.)

This is from the [IntentFilter Documetation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is easily done using the `PackageManager`:

```
ComponentName cnShortcutActivity = new ComponentName("my.package", "my.package.ShortcutActivity");
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(cnShortcutActivity, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```